# How update columns that ends with particular text?

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, where-clause

Suppose Table domains contains a cloumn 'dname'. It consists of 'india.com', russia.net', 'brazil.com', 'canada.biz' etc. I need to update table 'domain' where rows of column 'name' ends with .com. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE domains SET col_name = 'column_value' WHERE dname LIKE '%.com';
```

Syntax for this one is

```
UPDATE table_name SET col_name = 'column_value' WHERE column_name LIKE '%___';
```

Comment: Do this code update a value like "indico.com.sa" ? I need only updating values ends with ".com". Could you please clarify

Comment: @user1010966 you want to update for this one also "indico.com.sa"?

Comment: No I dont want to edit "indico.com.sa" . I just asked for clarification.

Comment: @user1010966 '%.com' updates only which is ends with .com for example google.com, yahoo.com. And not for indico.com.sa.

Comment: @user1010966 then i think my answer is sufficient? :)

Comment: Here "%" substitute for zero or more characters. Thanks Naveen

Comment: Yes yes. pleasure to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
update 
domain
set column='your value'
where 
`name` like '%.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use wild card in SQL for your refrence [LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp)